# Probability, basic statistics

Tags: probability

I am new at this subject, I have a question, I am working on it for couple hours but I can not trust my answers could you please help me,

```
The probability that a certain type of electronic component
will fail during the first hour of operation is 0.05. If 200 components are tested
independently,
1. What is the expected number of defective components in a given hour?
2. What is the probability that the number of defective components is at most
two?
```

My answer is for the first one; Fail: 0.005 so %5 and for 200 hundred answer is 10 ? But I don't have any idea for the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probability all good + probability exactly 1 bad + probability exactly 2 bad.

$$\left[(0.95)^{(200)}\right] + \left[\binom{200}{1}(0.05)^{(1)}(0.95)^{(199)}\right] + \left[\binom{200}{2}(0.05)^{(2)}(0.95)^{(198)}\right].$$

Comment: Is it for the first or the second question?

Comment: 2nd question : you nailed the first question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, So first one is true.. now I can understand the second one :)